# Can we use nouns or pronouns other than "you" to create a scenario that might occur?

Tags: word-choice, generic-noun-phrases, discourse-context

I often see texts like Example 1 that create an scenario that might occur. But they are often written with "You."

My question is:

"Can we write using other nouns or pronouns like Example 2 or 3?"

or

"What is the advantage of using 'you'?"

Example 1

> Sometimes you don't feel like going to the class. Maybe you broke up with your boyfriend. Maybe a friend said something mean to you that made you down.

Example 2

> Sometimes a person doesn't feel like doing her work. Maybe she broke up with her boyfriend. Maybe a friend said something mean to her that made her down.

Example 3

> Sometimes a student doesn't feel like going to the class. Maybe she broke up with her boyfriend. Maybe a friend said something mean to her that made her down.

Answer (score 1):

"You", the second person pronoun, is addressing a listener.
You could also use "I" for your scenario.

The advantage of either is that using them may avoid having to make awkward choices about the gender of other pronouns.

There is also "one". *Sometimes one doesn't feel like going to class.* That has a formal feeling that is better confined to a single statement, not describing an entire scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about options for **generic reference**—talking about an non-specific person in a hypothetical scenario. You need to decide how to refer to the person when you first mention them, and when you refer back to them.

- **First mention:** How to introduce a generic person into the story? You could use a [generic pronoun like *you* or *one*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-one-you-we-they); or an indefinite noun phrase like *someone*, *a person*, *a student*, etc.
- **Subsequent mentions:** Once you've mentioned the person you can refer back to them with standard pronouns. If the first mention was a genderless third person expression like *a student*, you have to decide whether to introduce a gender arbitrarily (*he* or *she*), or use gender-neutral *they*, or avoid pronouns altogether (*the student*, *that student*).